# Argument passed to function is not an instance of some class error

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having this error when try to call a method from my controller:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   RPNIBundle\Controller\CraueController::processFlow() must be an
>   instance of RPNIBundle\Controller\FormFlowInterface, instance of
>   RPNIBundle\Form\RegistroProductoFlow given, called in
>   /var/www/html/src/RPNIBundle/Controller/CraueController.php on line 21
>   and defined in
>   /var/www/html/src/RPNIBundle/Controller/CraueController.php line 29

I can't get where I am making the mistake so I could use a little help, this is what I have done:

**src/RPNIBundle/Controller/CraueController.php**

```
class CraueController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/rpni/registro/craue", name="registro-craue")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function registroSolicitudProductoAction()
    {
        $flow = $this->get('registrarProducto.form.flow');
        $flow->setAllowDynamicStepNavigation(true);

        // @todo add this to use statement
        return $this->processFlow(new \ComunBundle\Entity\Producto(), $flow); 
    }

    protected function processFlow($formData, FormFlowInterface $flow)
    {
        $flow->bind($formData);

        $form = $submittedForm = $flow->createForm();
        if ($flow->isValid($submittedForm)) {
            $flow->saveCurrentStepData($submittedForm);

            if ($flow->nextStep()) {
                $form = $flow->createForm();
            } else {
                $flow->reset();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_FormFlow_start'));
            }
        }

        if ($flow->redirectAfterSubmit($submittedForm)) {
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $params = $this->get('craue_formflow_util')->addRouteParameters(array_merge($request->query->all(), $request->attributes->get('_route_params')), $flow);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($request->attributes->get('_route'), $params));
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'flow' => $flow,
            'formData' => $formData,
        );
    }
}
```

**src/RPNIBundle/Form/RegistroProductoFlow.php**

```
class RegistroProductoFlow extends FormFlow
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registroSolicitudProducto';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function loadStepsConfig()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Datos Solicitud',
                'type' => new RegistroProductoFormType(),
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Datos Producto',
                'type' => $this->formType
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Pagos',
                'type' => $this->formType
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Confirmación',
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getFormOptions($step, array $options = array())
    {
        $options = parent::getFormOptions($step, $options);
        $options['cascade_validation'] = true;

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**src/RPNIBundle/Form/Type/RegistroProductoFormType.php**

```
class RegistroProductoFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
                ->add('tipo_tramite', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'ComunBundle:TipoTramite',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => "Tipo de Trámite",
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('q')
                                ->where('q.activo = :valorActivo')
                                ->setParameter('valorActivo', true);
                    }
                ))
                ->add('oficina_regional', 'entity', array(
                    'mapped' => FALSE,
                    'class' => 'ComunBundle:OficinaRegional',
                    'property' => 'nombre',
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'label' => "Oficina Regional",
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('q')
                                ->where('q.activo = :valorActivo')
                                ->setParameter('valorActivo', true);
                    }
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registroProducto';
    }
}
```

**src/RPNIBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    registrarProducto.form:
        class: RPNIBundle\Form\Type\RegistroProductoFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: registrarProducto }

    registrarProducto.form.flow:
        class: RPNIBundle\Form\RegistroProductoFlow
        parent: craue.form.flow
        scope: request
```

Can any give me some help? I'm digging through the code but I can not find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you forgot a use statement at the top of your controller class?

```
use Craue\FormFlowBundle\Form\FormFlowInterface;
```

That function (`processFlow`) doesn't belong in a controller btw. Controllers should take a `Request` and return a `Response`. :)

Comment: Hmmm you're right but I take it from [this](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowDemoBundle/blob/3.0.x/Controller/FormFlowDemoController.php#L85) example from the same bundle author, according to you where should be place it?

Comment: @ReynierPM Oh, I see now. Yeah, I see he's trying to keep his code DRY, but after the `// flow finished` section of the function, you're going to have a big problem. You're trying to have one function handle the final successful submission of multiple form flows. I don't see how that's possible without a huge, unmaintainable if/elseif/else or switch block. I'd personally create a Model folder and handle each separately...somehow. lol